# Why TreeMap constructor undefined for comparator type with same template value parameter type?

Tags: generics, constructor, comparator, treemap

The value type of my map is a  `List<Pair<Integer, String>>`

I want to sort it by the left side of first pair in the list. But there is an error said:

> The constructor 
>   `TreeMap<String,List<Pair<Integer,String>>> (Comparator<List<Pair<Integer,String>>>)` 
>    is undefined

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.TreeMap;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.tuple.Pair;

Map<String, List<Pair<Integer, String>>> data = new HashMap<String, List<Pair<Integer,String>>>();  
            ....
Comparator<List<Pair<Integer, String>>> valueComparator = new Comparator<List<Pair<Integer, String>>>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(List<Pair<Integer, String>> o1,
                    List<Pair<Integer, String>> o2) {
                int rzt = o1.get(0).getLeft() - o2.get(0).getLeft();
                return rzt;
            }  
           };

           TreeMap<String, List<Pair<Integer, String>>> sortedByValues = new TreeMap<String, List<Pair<Integer, String>>>(valueComparator);
           sortedByValues.putAll(data);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Comparator` should compare keys and not values. The constructor of [`TreeMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#TreeMap%28java.util.Comparator%29) has the following signature:

```
public TreeMap(Comparator<? super K> comparator)
```

where `K` is the type parameter of the Key: `Class TreeMap<K,V>`